# Update WSP solution Compatibility mode

Tags: 2013, solution-package

We migrated from SP2010 to SP2013.

I installed and deployed a wsp without specifying the compatibility mode.Now after migration,visual upgrade is getting delayed because of which the wsp is not working as expected in 2010 mode.

Is there a way to update the compatibility mode for a deployed wsp solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've searched for something similar for a long time, and never found a command to *update* a solution and its compatibility level.
So, I end up with retracting the WSP, and then installing it back with the *CompatibilityLevel* parameter in PowerShell.

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity <Name_of_WSP> -CompatibilityLevel "14,15" -GACDeployment [-WebApplication …]
```